# How to use a variable as a DOM object within scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, loops, dom

I have a lot of `functions` going on that will be duplicated for multiple instances, and I'm trying to streamline everything and make the `functions` easily reused.

To avoid hard coding values, I'm trying to establish a parent `ID` to be able to run some of the more in depth `loops`.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/hgwNU/

**So if I have...**

#### HTML

```
<div id="one">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div id="two">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

#### Script

```
var playerOne = $('#one');

$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).text('Changed');
});
```

I tried something like:

```
$(playerOne + "p").each(function() {
```

But I got an `object conflict` error.

**How would I incorporate `playerOne` variable in this example to only target the `p` elements in `#one` instead of all of them?**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/hgwNU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)/[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) based what kind of descendants you are looking for

```
playerOne.find('p').each(...)l //for p elements under `#one` in any level
playerOne.children('p').each(...)l //for p elements which are direct children of `#one`
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgwNU/1/). And the first example works best, as I have some deeply nested descendents. Much appreciated!

Comment: @NicholasHazel also there is no need for the each, you could just say `playerOne.children('p').text('Changed');`

Comment: Well, my project is significantly more robust. I just wrote a very simple demo here. If you want to see the whole thing, feel free to poke around here - [Project](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBGLb/1/). I have a lot more going on than just changing the text, but thank you for the elaboration :-). Just a brainfart on the syntax :-P

Comment: Since we're here, one other quick question? Can you use $('#jQueryObjects') as parameters for functions, ie - `functionName($('jQueryObjects'){}` when calling them?

Comment: @NicholasHazel not in the function declaration... but when you call a function you can pass it as a argument like `function x(y) {//use y here}` then later `x($('jquery'))`

Comment: Of course not in the declaration :-). But it doesn't appear to be working...? [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hgwNU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply

```
$('p',playerOne).each(function(i,v){
    //....
 })
```